# Redirect using htaccess using a slash or underscore as separators

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

Ive searched high and low for this scenario but keep running into more simple solutions

for example

```
RewriteRule ^stays-the-same/[^A-Z]*[A-Z] %1 [R=301,L,NE]
```

The goal is to see if the url fits either of these possibilities

`/stays-the-same/variable/*`

`/stays-the-same/variable_*`

`/item-1/stays-the-same/variable_*`

`/item-1/stays-the-same/variable_*`

*Regardless of case for the variable or anything that comes after it*

for it to 301 to the lower case version of `/item-1/stays-the-same/variable` - and always to the `https://www.` version.

The asterisk denotes anything, for example multiple paths, numbers, underscores etc

Any suggestions are very much appreciated.

**Edit**

`"variable"` is only letters or hyphens,  upper or lower case.

`"item-1"` is static text and should always be in the end URL , even if it wasn't there as in the first two examples.

Everything after the variable is discarded, any trailing `/` or `_` as well.

**Edit 2**  - the full `.htaccess` file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond expr "tolower(%{REQUEST_URI}) =~ m#^((/[^/]+)?/[^/]+/[a-z-]+)[/_]#"
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}@%1 ^(?:www\.)?(.+?)\.?@(.+)
RewriteRule ^(item-1/)?stays-the-same/([a-z-]*[A-Z][a-z-]*)[/_] https://www.%1%2 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^212\.212\.212\.212$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]





RewriteCond expr "tolower(%{REQUEST_URI}) =~ /(.*)/"
RewriteRule ^stays-the-same/[^A-Z]*[A-Z] %1 [R=301,L,NE]




RewriteRule \.(jpe?g|png|gif|ico|bmp|pdf|docx?|txt|css|js)$ - [L,NC]

RewriteRule ^([^\s%20]+)(?:\s|%20)+([^\s%20]+)((?:\s|%20)+.*)$ $1-$2$3 [N,DPI]
RewriteRule ^([^\s%20]+)(?:\s|%20)+(.*)$ /$1-$2 [L,R=301,DPI]




RewriteRule ^signup/ https://www.example.com/signup [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^word/ https://www.example.com/other-word [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !pagespeed


RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^PageSpeed=noscript$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* %{REQUEST_URI}? [L,R=301]

Header set Content-Language "en"




RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)option\=com_flag($|&)
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)view\=inventory($|&)
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)ajax\=true($|&)
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)country($|&)
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ /stays-the-same? [L,R=301]



## No directory listings
IndexIgnore *

## Can be commented out if causes errors, see notes above.
Options +FollowSymlinks
Options -Indexes

 
## Mod_rewrite in use.


RewriteEngine On

#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} stays-the-same
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]

## Begin - Rewrite rules to block out some common exploits.
# If you experience problems on your site then comment out the operations listed
# below by adding a # to the beginning of the line.
# This attempts to block the most common type of exploit `attempts` on Joomla!
#
# Block any script trying to base64_encode data within the URL.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} base64_encode[^(]*\([^)]*\) [OR]
# Block any script that includes a <script> tag in URL.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (<|%3C)([^s]*s)+cript.*(>|%3E) [NC,OR]
# Block any script trying to set a PHP GLOBALS variable via URL.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} GLOBALS(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2}) [OR]
# Block any script trying to modify a _REQUEST variable via URL.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _REQUEST(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2})
# Return 403 Forbidden header and show the content of the root homepage
RewriteRule .* index.php [F]
#
## End - Rewrite rules to block out some common exploits.



## Begin - Custom redirects

# 301 --- https://www.example.com/?ref=producthunt => https://www.example.com
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)ref\=producthunt($|&)
RewriteRule ^$ /? [L,R=301]

# 301 --- https://www.example.com/signup?view=item-2 => https://www.example.com/signup
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)view\=item-2($|&)
RewriteRule ^signup$ /signup? [L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^stay-same/(.*)$ /shoes/$1 [QSA,R=301,L]





#
# If you need to redirect some pages, or set a canonical non-www to
# www redirect (or vice versa), place that code here. Ensure those
# redirects use the correct RewriteRule syntax and the [R=301,L] flags.
#
## End - Custom redirects

##
# Uncomment the following line if your webserver's URL
# is not directly related to physical file paths.
# Update Your Joomla! Directory (just / for root).
##

# RewriteBase /

## Begin - Joomla! core SEF Section.
#
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
#
# If the requested path and file is not /index.php and the request
# has not already been internally rewritten to the index.php script
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php
# and the requested path and file doesn't directly match a physical file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# and the requested path and file doesn't directly match a physical folder
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# internally rewrite the request to the index.php script
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
#
## End - Joomla! core SEF Section.



php_value upload_max_filesize 5M
php_value post_max_size 10M
php_value memory_limit 320M
```

Comment: What can `variable` contain? Only letters as your pseudo-rule would appear to suggest? What is `item-1` - just static text? And should it always redirect to `/item-1/...` even when did not appear in the requested URL (first 2 examples)? And everything after the `variable` is discarded?

Comment: The question has been updated and yes , variable is only letters or hyphens , upper or lower case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE:** Several changes made to the rule/conditions to allow an all lowercase *variable* and to enforce the `/item-1` prefix on the resulting URL-path. The part of the URL-path after the *variable* is discarded - *something* is always discarded.

Try the following (requires Apache 2.4):

```
RewriteCond expr "tolower(%{REQUEST_URI}) =~ m#^(?:/item-1)?/([^/]+/[a-z-]+)[/_]#"
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}@%1 ^(?:www\.)?(.+?)\.?@(.+)
RewriteRule ^(item-1/)?stays-the-same/([a-z-]+)[/_] https://www.%1/item-1/%2 [NC,R=301,L]
```

The `RewriteRule` *pattern* establishes whether the requested URL-path matches one of the possible URLs *and* the `variable` contains only letters or hyphens <s>and at least one of those letters is uppercase</s>. The `NC` flag ensures this is a case-insensitive match, so the *variable* can be upper/lowercase.

The first *condition* then converts the URL-path to lowercase. The part of the lowercased URL-path up to and including the `variable` only is captured (excluding the optional `/item-1` prefix), which is passed to the following *condition* in the `%1` backreference.

The second *condition* then extracts the part of the hostname, less the `www.` prefix (if any) which is stored in the `%1` backreference (again) *and* passes the lowercased URL-path (from the first *condition*) on to the following rule in the `%2` backreference.

Note that the `%2` backreference in the *substitution* string (that represents the URL-path) now excludes the slash prefix, so the slash is now included in the *substitution* string - I think this is more readable than including the slash as part of the backreference (as it was previously).

The `/item-1` prefix needs to be hardcoded in the *substitution* string since this is *optional* in the requested URL-path.

---

You could simplify this and *hardcode* the www hostname instead and avoid the second condition. For example:

```
RewriteCond expr "tolower(%{REQUEST_URI}) =~ m#^(?:/item-1)?/([^/]+/[a-z-]+)[/_]#"
RewriteRule ^(item-1/)?stays-the-same/([a-z-]+)[/_] https://www.example.com/item-1/%1 [NC,R=301,L]
```

This uses the backreference `%1` directly from first condition in the *substitution* string.

---

Test first with a 302 (temporary) redirect to avoid potential caching issues and make sure the browser cache is cleared before testing.

Comment: ++ve for nice solution. For `m#^((/[^/]+)?/[^/]+/[^/]+)[/_]#` do we need to `#` as starting and end also, as a syntax?

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 the regular expression needs delimiters - default would be the `/`, but that'd mean escaping all the slashes _inside_ the expression. The `m`format allows to chose a different delimiter; https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/expr.html#other

Comment: Really appreciate the through answer @MrWhite - unfortunately it doesn't seem to work. It doesn't trigger for any of the URLs - Im on Apache 2.4.54 - you also mentioned " and at least one of those letters is uppercase." for the variable. The variable can be all lower-case. It won't trigger for /stays-the-same/Hello_World_123-09 or /stays-the-same/hello_world_123-456

Comment: @Nick I've updated my answer slightly by changing the regex in the condition to better match the _variable_ - although this doesn't really change anything.

Comment: @Nick "The variable can be all lower-case." - Although if the variable is all lowercase then there's nothing to do, since it's already lowercase. Or is there always something after the variable that should be removed? It should trigger for `/stays-the-same/Hello_World_123-09` (and redirect to `/stays-the-same/hello`), but not currently for `/stays-the-same/hello_world_123-456`. I assume from those two examples that the "variable" is just the `Hello` (or `hello`) part?

Comment: @Nick What other directives do you have in your `.htaccess` file? Could you update your question with your complete `.htaccess` file with these directives in place. Thanks.

Comment: @Nick "although this doesn't really change anything" - Just to clarify, the change I made to the regex (ie. from `[^/]+` to `[a-z-]+`) is an important "fix", but it wouldn't actually make it "trigger" if it didn't before.

Comment: I see, thanks. It did change things, or it could just be because I moved the rule to the top of the htaccess. With /stays-the-same/Hello_World_123-09 its doing the correct thing but missing the /item-1/ - in this example it should 301 to /item-1/stays-the-same/hello and it doesnt seem to trigger if its all lower case and/or the first separator is a / instead of a _

Comment: Thank you again for this @MrWhite - htaccess added to the question, it does work for /item-1/stays-the-same/words-here/random_text_270-210 - 301s to  /item-1/stays-the-same/words-here

Comment: @Nick "because I moved the rule to the top of the htaccess" - Yes, most probably - the order of the rules is important. (This would certainly have conflicted with the rule further down that simply lowercases the URL.) "but missing the `/item-1/`" - sorry, I overlooked that - I've now enforced the `/item-1` prefix (unfortunately this does need to be repeated a few times in the rule - since it is _optional_, it can't be captured). I've allowed an all lowercase _variable_. I've updated my answer with several changes to the rule.

Comment: @Nick "first separator is a / instead of a _" - it shouldn't matter whether the separator is `/` or `_` (at least not after my earlier update). Make sure the browser cache is clear (and test first with a 302 temp redirect).

Comment: I see and the updates worked, lower and upper case as well. This rule has turned  redirects that were once 4 hops, to 1. - this is very much appreciated @MrWhite